# Apply function to all elements of parameter pack from a variadic function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Consider the following (not working!) example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename type> void print(const type & item)
{
    std :: cout << item << std :: endl;
}

template <typename... types> void printall(const types & ... items)
{
    print(items)...;
}

int main()
{
    printall(1, 2, "hello");
}
```

Here I have a function `print` that simply prints out its argument, and a variadic function `printall` that accepts a pack of arguments. Now, what I would like to do is to simply have `printall` apply `print` to each element of the pack `items`. How can I get that done?

**Note**: I am *not* asking how to print a pack of values. I am aware of the existence of fold expressions and I know I could just throw the whole `items` in `std::cout` using them. Here `print` is just an example, could be any function.

How can I get that done? This sounds like something that should remarkably simple to do and yet I couldn't find any (reasonable) syntax to do it.

Comment: i dont understand why fold expressions is not the answer. `print(items)...;` does not compile?

Comment: No, `print(items)...;` does not compile, I get the following error: `error: expected ';' after expression`.

Comment: if your code does not compile, please include the error messages you get in the question. btw i think you are looking for `std::invoke` or `std::apply` (they are quite different but I always confuse them)

Comment: `(print(items),...);` Parens and comma are required.

Comment: Ok. Wow. That works. But what kind of syntax is this...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What I would like to do is to simply have `printall` apply `print` to
>   each element of the pack items. How can I get that done?

### Option - 1

As user [@liliscent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605791/liliscent) and user [@max66](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6022656/max66) suggested in the comments, 
in C++11/ C++14 you can use the following hacky-way which act act like *fold expressions* in C++17.

<kbd>[SEE HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MWsC2zQsSkh1G9xe)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename type> void print(const type& item)
{
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}

template <typename... types> 
void printall (const types&... items)
{
    using dummy = int[];
    (void)dummy { 0, (print(items), 0)... };
}
```

---

### Option - 2

If the above does not look like good enough, provide a classical variadic templates overload as *a wrapper/ helper* between your `printall()` and `print()` functions, so that each template function arguments can be accessed in `print()`.

<kbd>[SEE HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nGtbaHaWCuvZbkdG)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type> void print(const Type& item)
{
    std::cout << item << '\n';  // print each argument
}

namespace helper 
{
    void printall() {}          // nontemplate overload for last call(i.e, no arguments call)

    template<typename FirstArg, typename... Types>
    void printall(const FirstArg& firstItem, Types&&... items)  
    {
        ::print(firstItem);                             // call print() for each argument
        helper::printall(std::forward<Types>(items)...);// calls the same wrapper::printalll()
    }
}

template <typename... Types> void printall(const Types& ... items)
{
    helper::printall(items...); // calls the wrapper::printall()
}
```

---

### Option - 3

However, if you have access to the C++17, just use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). That provides a clean(non-hacky) and less amount of code.

<kbd>[SEE HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bsG53MlVGlvuNfGq)</kbd>

```
template <typename type> void print(const type& item)
{
    std::cout << item << '\n';
}

template <typename... types> void printall(const types&... items)
{
    (print(items),...);
}
```

Comment: In C++11, a succinct way would be `using dummy = int[]; (void) dummy{(print(items), 0)...};`.

Comment: In C++17 you could simply write `template <typename ... types> void printall (types const & ... items) { (std::cout << item << std::endl, ...); }` (also `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`, to avoid unnecessary flushing)

Comment: @max66 Yes that's exactly what OP do not want to have. He has mentioned it in the comments as **Note**.  :) But for sure `'\n'`, which you will see in my first answer. I will add to the second too. ;)

Comment: Sorry... not seen; anyway, in C++11/C++14 (as suggested by liliscent) you can try something as `template <typename ... types> void printall (types const & ... items) { using dummy = int[]; (void)dummy { 0, (print(items), 0)... }; );`

Comment: @max66 Okay. That looks interesting... Couldn't understand when *liliscent* wrote that. Thanks for clearing the doubt. Let me try with that too.

Comment: It's a common C++11/C++14 alternative to C++17 template folding (very useful in C++14 writing `constexpr` template functions).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183580/discussion-between-jejo-and-max66).

Comment: Instead of `(void)dummy { 0, (print(items), 0)... };` you should use `(void)dummy { 0, ((void)print(items), 0)... };` in case `print` returns something funny which overloads the comma operator.